# php imap mail body encoding

Tags: php, encoding, imap

I'm building a mail module for my web app. At my current point, I'm trying to fetch the mail body and decode it correctly. However, when I come across international characters in the mail, it doesn't decode them correctly.

ex. I have a raw email body:

```
--001a11c126f6bd3aa804f575bd85 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable ss -- s Niels S=F8nderb=E6k --001a11c126f6bd3aa804f575bd85 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

ss
-- s
Ni= els S=F8nderb=E6k
--001a11c126f6bd3aa804f575bd85--
```

This is the result after decoding:

```
ss
-- s
Niels S�nderb�k
```

The `Niels S�nderb�k` should be `Niels Sønderbæk`. I've only seen this problem, when dealing with international characters. Does anybody know how to fix it? I've included my decoding code below. It's taken from http://www.sitepoint.com/exploring-phps-imap-library-1/.

```
<?php

$imap = imap_open(...);

$uid = ...

function getBody($uid, $imap) {
    $body = get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/HTML");
    // if HTML body is empty, try getting text body
    if ($body == "") {
        $body = get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/PLAIN");
    }
    return $body;
}

function get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $structure = false, $partNumber = false) {
    if (!$structure) {
           $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $uid, FT_UID);
    }
    if ($structure) {
        if ($mimetype == get_mime_type($structure)) {
            if (!$partNumber) {
                $partNumber = 1;
            }
            $text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNumber, FT_UID);
            switch ($structure->encoding) {
                case 3: return imap_base64($text);
                case 4: return imap_qprint($text);
                default: return imap_utf8($text);
           }
       }

        // multipart 
        if ($structure->type == 1) {
            foreach ($structure->parts as $index => $subStruct) {
                $prefix = "";
                if ($partNumber) {
                    $prefix = $partNumber . ".";
                }
                $data = get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $subStruct, $prefix . ($index + 1));
                if ($data) {
                    return $data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function get_mime_type($structure) {
    $primaryMimetype = array("TEXT", "MULTIPART", "MESSAGE", "APPLICATION", "AUDIO", "IMAGE", "VIDEO", "OTHER");

    if ($structure->subtype) {
       return $primaryMimetype[(int)$structure->type] . "/" . $structure->subtype;
    }
    return "TEXT/PLAIN";
}

echo getBody($uid,$imap);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the header says it's iso8859-1 character set encoding, but you've only undone the transfer encoding. You still need to do a character set conversion from the email to you Web apps character set, presumably utf8.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem.
To solve a create function `getCharset`:

```php
private function getCharset($structure)
{
    if ($structure->ifdparameters && count($structure->dparameters ) > 0 )
    {
        foreach ($structure->dparameters as $child )
        {
            if ( strtolower($child->attribute ) == 'charset')
            {
                return strtolower($child->value);
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $structure->ifparameters && count($structure->parameters) > 0 )
    {
        foreach ($structure->parameters as $child)
        {
            if ( strtolower($child->attribute) == 'charset')
            {
                return strtolower($child->value);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and before return the body I convert:

```php
...
$text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNumber, FT_UID);
switch ($structure->encoding) {
    case 3:
        $text = imap_base64($text);
    case 4:
        $text = imap_qprint($text);
}

$chartset = $this->getCharset($structure);
if($chartset) {
    return mb_convert_encoding($text, 'utf-8', $chartset);
}

return $text;
```

Comment: You're missing https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php